# Put border on a shape

Tags: css

i'm trying to insert a border to a css shape that i created.

Here the css shape that i created

[image: 1]

Here what happens when i insert the border

[image: 2]

What do i need to change on my css?

```
.jologo{
   width: 200px;
   height: 0; 
   border-bottom: 40px solid #262627;
   border-left: 5px solid #f15c5c;
   border-right: 40px solid transparent;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Ok, i will do it, wait just a minute

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q37MB/

Comment: I already did it, i inserted a span inside the div, and i inserted the border inside this span, now is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing the HTML, you could always add the border via an absolutely pseudo element. Just be sure to relatively position the parent element. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/A8259/)

```
.jologo:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    background:#f15c5c;
    height:40px;
    left:0;
    width:5px;
}
```

The reason your border wasn't working was because [this is how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work) borders are added to elements:

[image]

As a result, you will get a border that is skewed if the height of the element is `0`.

Comment: Nice, i will thumbs up your question